# How to upload a folder with 3000 text documents on repl.it?

Tags: python, api, discord, bots, replit

I am currently coding a discord bot and I want to host it online and the only solution I found was using repl.it.

I tried uploading my folder (3MB) of text files on repl.it, but I always get an error from the website, saying "Ran out of memory".

Is it possible to put the folder somewhere online, like in a free online database, and then access it with python script from repl.it, using an API? If so, please explain with code source.

Or any others solutions/ documentations?

Comment: What happened when you tried putting `discord bot hosting python` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=discord+bot+hosting+python)? When I try that, I see many things that aren't repl.it. What happened when you tried searching the repl.it documentation for information about size restrictions?

Answer (score 1):

Repl.it has a Maximum Storage of 400MB for the repl, but there are many apis for online file storage like mega.py(https://pypi.org/project/mega.py/)  or google-drive(https://pypi.org/project/google-drive/). You can also switch your Hoster by Downloading your discord Bot as a Zip Extract it and write "Free Discord Bot Hosting" in google for example PenguinBots.eu.

Edit the Code Documentation is writen officially by ggogle: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python